# How to get next and previous item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How to get the next item, previous item? For example, an active item 3-th, when I clicking to the next button, the function returns 5-th item.

My JSON data:

```
const DataJ = [
     { date: '2018-05-17T15:11:23.351Z'}, 
     { date: '2018-01-17T15:11:23.351Z'}, 
     { date: '2018-10-17T15:11:23.351Z'},
     { date: '2018-10-17T15:11:23.351Z'},
     { date: '2018-12-17T15:11:23.351Z'}
];
```

Prev and next functions.

```
const nextItem = () => {
     // Next json item
     console.log();
}

const prevItem = () => {
     // Prev json item
     console.log();
}

<div>
     <button type="button" className="control-btn" onClick="prevItem"> Prev </button>
     <button type="button" className="control-btn" onClick="nextItem"> Next </button>
</div>
```

I tried to use this method:

```
const prevItem = () => {
         const { DataJ } = this.props;
            const curDate = new Date(Date.now());
            console.log(DataJ[0]);
            return DataJ.reduce(
                (a, b) =>
                    new Date(b.date) <= curDate
                        ? b : a,
                DataJ[0]
            );
    }
```

Comment: _"For example, an active item 3-th, when I clicking to the next button, the function returns 5-th item"_  You mean skipping 4th because it is the same date?

Comment: If you sorted the array by date at the beginning, then your next/prev functions could simply select by index. You'd be iterating through the data once to sort it rather than iterating through it every time "Prev" or "Next" is clicked.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What makes an item the current (active)  item, is it stored somewhere or is there a pointer? What you mean by if the current item is the third, but clicking on the next button current becomes the fifth? Is the sequencing criteria "select closest next date skipping equal entries"? Are the entries ordered or you might have sort it first?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can iterate your items:

```js
  var myApp = window.MyApp || {};
    const DataJ = [
       { date: '2018-05-17T15:11:23.351Z'}, 
       { date: '2018-01-17T15:11:23.351Z'}, 
       { date: '2018-10-17T15:11:23.351Z'},
       { date: '2018-10-17T15:11:23.351Z'},
       { date: '2018-12-17T15:11:23.351Z'}
  ];
  myApp.currentIndex = 0;
  myApp.currentItem = function () {
    return DataJ[myApp.currentIndex];
  };
  myApp.prevItem = function () {
    myApp.currentIndex--;
    return myApp.currentItem();
  };
  myApp.nextItem = function () {
    myApp.currentIndex++;
    return myApp.currentItem();
  };

console.log(myApp.currentItem());
console.log(myApp.nextItem());
console.log(myApp.nextItem());
console.log(myApp.prevItem());
```

As per your request, 3rd to 5th, you need to add a few checks before switching.
I would guess (since the question is not clear), that you want the NEXT DATE item, but the code i provided should allow you to get very close to that by yourself.

P.S.
You should also think about what happens when FIRST/LAST item is reached.